# Location of scriptlet.nl file in netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Can anyone please let me know where the file scriptlet.nl is located. In the code the path is defined as app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl. But I searched on the entire File Cabinet and could not seen this file. I am very new to netsuite. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that I have never see that particular page, off the top of my head.  But, the *.nl pages are the NetSuite pages.  For instance, when you are looking at a script record in NetSuite the URL is something like this: /app/common/scripting/script.nl?id=1234.  The ID tells you which script it is looking at, and the filename is listed on that page as well.  But the script.nl page is not actually soemthing that you can touch as a customer.

Comment: Ok. So, is there any way to identify the id given in the url is mapped to which script?

Comment: Yes.  That would be with the ID parameter that should follow.  Do you have the full URL to share?

Comment: Yes. /app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=180&deploy=1&compid=3927902&h=2403e5b2d1216ce99934&itemid=.... So, if I want to edit the script, where I can find it in the backend? I checked in File Cabinet and not seen anything related to this.

Comment: That URL helps.  So, that looks like you are looking at a suitelet URL.  See the "script=180" part?  That is the script ID.  If you have access to the scripts (which I'm assuming you should) go here: /app/common/scripting/script.nl?id=180.  That will be the script record.  From there, you can edit the script, get the actual filename, and link to the file location.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. Got it.

Answer (score 3):

The *.nl paths are used by the Netsuite internal router. There are no scripts that an end user can get at or see.

Just think of them as managing references to Netsuite's internal processes.

Comment: Ok understand. Thanks!